# MVC3 JSON Ajax error

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to make an ajax sending data in JSON from a partial view. I get a System.ArgumentException: Invalid JSON primitive: undefined.
When I evaluate the object in a browser data contains an int and two strings. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Partial View

```
@model FTD.Models.FTDAccountExtended
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
<fieldset>
<legend>Update Policy Number</legend>
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.account.ftd_accountsid)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.OldPolicyNumber)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.account.ftd_policyno)
<input type="button" value="update" id="update" />
</fieldset>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#update").click(function () {
         var myUrl = '@Url.Content("~/")' + '/Maintenance/UpdatePolicyNumber';
         var data = [{ 'ClientNumber': parseInt($("#account_ftd_accountsid").val()), 'OldPolicyNumber': $("#OldPolicyNumber").val(), 'NewPolicyNumber': $("#account_ftd_policyno").val()}];
         $.ajax({
             url: myUrl,
             type: 'POST',
             data: data,
             contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
             success: function (data) {
                 alert(data.message);
             },
             error: function (errMsg) {
                 alert("Error", errMsg);
             }
         });
     });
 });
```

The controller method is

```
public ActionResult UpdatePolicyNumber(int ClientNumber, string OldPolicyNumber, string NewPolicyNumber)
{
    var message = string.Format("UpdatePolicyNumber CN:{0} OP:{1} NP:{2}", ClientNumber, OldPolicyNumber, NewPolicyNumber);
    if (_log.IsDebugEnabled)
        _log.Debug(message);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(NewPolicyNumber) && ClientNumber > 0)
    {
        _entities = new CloseFTD_Entities();
        _entities.UpdatePolicyNumber(ClientNumber, OldPolicyNumber, NewPolicyNumber, User.Identity.Name);

     }
     return Json
        (
           new
           {
               message = message
           },
           JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
         );
}
```

Comment: can you show in here the structure of your json?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699749/valid-json-to-create-a-jstree-nodes-dynamically/9699836#9699836 

i hope that link can help you..

Comment: and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730788/cannot-call-the-json-result-in-jquery

Comment: Essentially I want to pass the entry parameters of the controller method [{ 'ClientNumber': 83688, 'OldPolicyNumber': "WWW4567", 'NewPolicyNumber': "WWW1234" }]

Comment: wheer you want to parsing that data? in server side or client side?

Comment: I want to pass it from the client to the controller.

Comment: you Policy Numbers are not setup correctly in your JSON, it looks like you don't have double quotes around the jQuery `.val()` functions when setting up the JSOn data string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just try posting the the data as a java script object (as Marc mentioned above)
and remove the content type attribute.

Comment: Using Marcs change and removing the content type did it many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
 success: function (data) {
                 alert(data.success);
             },
```

shouldn't this be

```
 success: function (data) {
                 alert(data.message);
             },
```

Comment: You quite right that is incorrect. However not actually triggering the controller, the error is in the data I am passing across.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here

```
var data = [{ 'ClientNumber': parseInt($("#account_ftd_accountsid").val()), 'OldPolicyNumber': $("#OldPolicyNumber").val(), 'NewPolicyNumber': $("#account_ftd_policyno").val()}];
```

You are building an array - but your controller excepts the direct values, so just remove the `[]` brackets:

```
var data = { 'ClientNumber': parseInt($("#account_ftd_accountsid").val()), 'OldPolicyNumber': $("#OldPolicyNumber").val(), 'NewPolicyNumber': $("#account_ftd_policyno").val()};
```

That should work.

Comment: Tried removing the [] brackets, but still getting System.ArgumentException: Invalid JSON primitive: ClientNumber.